# Can't upload image to remote server using Appcelerator

Tags: request, titanium, appcelerator, image-uploading

The application I'm working uses an API developed by another team. I'm working on Titanium 2.1.2 and I'm trying to upload a photo using said API. I'm using Appcelerator's HTTPClient to make the request. Here's my code:

```
    var url = 'http://api.veramiko.com/albums/' + album.veramiko_id + '/photos';
    var photo = imageView.toBlob();

    var args = { //parameters sent to post photo
        file : photo,
        description : descriptionText
    };

    var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload : function(e){
            Ti.API.info(this.responseText); //Print the result
        },
        onerror : function(e){
            Ti.API.error(this.responseText); //Print the result
        },
        timeout : 60000
    });
    client.open('POST', url);
    client.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    client.setRequestHeader('Content-type', "multipart/form-data");
    client.send(args);
```

Token is a variable we use to authorize any requests made to the server. I thought that by only converting the image from the ImageView into Blob would be enough to send the photo, but the photo isn't uploaded. The post is created with the description but the photo isn't sent properly.

Do I need to add something else? Is it right to send the photo as a Blob?

**EDIT:** I read this [link](http://www.smokycogs.com/blog/titanium-tutorial-how-to-upload-a-file-to-a-server/) and I tried the following with no result:

```
    var url = 'http://api.veramiko.com/albums/' + album.veramiko_id + '/photos';
    var boundary = '-_1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    var photo = imageView.toBlob();

    var args = {
        file : photo,
        description : descriptionText.value
    };      

    var contentDisposition = "--" + boundary + "\r\n"; 
    contentDisposition += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";";
    contentDisposition += "filename=\"" + imageView.image + "\"\r\n\";";
    contentDisposition += "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";

    var fullContent = contentDisposition + photo  + "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

    alert(JSON.stringify(args));
    var token = JSON.parse(Ti.App.Properties.getString('loggedUser', 'No existe')).networks[0].token;
    var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload : function(e){
            Ti.API.info(this.responseText); //Print the result
        },
        onerror : function(e){
            Ti.API.error(this.responseText); //Print the result
        },
        timeout : 60000
    });
    client.open('POST', url);
    client.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "multipart/form-data; boundary=\"" + boundary + "\"");
    client.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'close');
    client.send(fullContent);
```

I tried to wrap the file with a Content-Disposition and Content-Type header with no result.

Comment: are u running on rails server ??

Comment: I'll have to ask to the API team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to solve this. Please refer to the following [link](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/88371/image-upload-directly-from-camera).

This is how my code looked in the end:

```
    // I put the contents of my image into a variable
var f = imageHolder.toImage();
    // I create a random name for the image
var tmpName = (new Date()).getTime().toString() + '.png';
    // I create a folder where I will store the photo temporally
var g = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'picturesToUpload');
if (!g.exists()) {
    // If the directory doesn't exist, make it
    g.createDirectory();
};
var photo = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'picturesToUpload', tmpName);
    // write the contents of the image into the file
photo.write(f);
    // I create my url with the albumId where I'll upload the picture
var url = 'http://api.veramiko.com/albums/' + albumId + '/photos';
var args = {
    file : photo.read(), // I read the contents of the file
    description : ''
}
var token = JSON.parse(Ti.App.Properties.getString('loggedUser', 'No existe')).networks[0].token;
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload : function(e){
        Ti.API.info('Info received from the uploading: ' + this.responseText);
    },
    onerror : function(e){
        Ti.API.debug('Error: ' + this.responseText);
    },
        timeout : 60000
});
client.open('POST', url);
    // these headers are important
client.setRequestHeader('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
client.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
client.send(args);
```

Hope this info helps more people.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you Clear what is you API Parameter. and where you want to use TOKEN.

```
var imageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    backgroundImage : "image.png",
});
    var url = 'http://api.veramiko.com/albums/' + album.veramiko_id + '/photos';


        var args = { //parameters sent to post photo
            file : imageView.backgroundImage,
            description : descriptionText,
            token : "Token",
        };

        var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
            onload : function(e){
                Ti.API.info(this.responseText); //Print the result
            },
            onerror : function(e){
                Ti.API.error(this.responseText); //Print the result
            },
            timeout : 60000
        });
        client.open('POST', url);
        client.setRequestHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data");
        client.setRequestHeader("Content-length", args.length);
        client.send(args);
```

Try This, I thought this is working for you...

Comment: well the token is a variable for the Authorization header that must be specified in said header to make any request to the server. I tried this but with no result, I'm starting to suspect the API team made a mistake since I've tried many different ways to upload the photo with no positive result. I guess I'll have to ask the moderators to close this question since I have to check with the API team.

Comment: The problem is that the photo isn't send to the server correctly, Titanium doesn't throw any error so I can't show you a log with an error. 
The server side doesn't receive the photo file, but still creates the post with the "photo" and the description, but no photo is shown, when clicking the photo it doesn't load anything so it stays that in a loading state. 
The server side receives an empty file parameter, I don't know why the photo isn't being sent.

Comment: Hey, in My case firstly. if i send my image in Blob formate with this header file then working properly.... withclient.setRequestHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data");
        client.setRequestHeader("Content-length", args.length);

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial, that covers on how to build an uploader.

[Titanium Mobile: Build an Image Uploader](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/titanium-mobile-build-an-image-uploader/)

Answer (score 0):

You case use this code to upload a file in form-data :

```
var baseurlAPI = "YOUR API BASEURL HERE";
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(pathToFile);

 if(file.exists()){
    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload: function(e) {
                Ti.API.log('success '+this.responseText);
       },
       onerror: function(e) {
                Ti.API.error(this.responseText);
        },
            timeout : -1
    });
    xhr.open('POST', baseurlAPI);
    xhr.send({
       file: file
    });
 }else{
    console.log('didnt exist ' + file.nativePath);
 }
```